# Pass variable to IIFE like NodeJS module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to pass a variable to a IIFE in another file (a module *required*) but it is ignored.

**index.js**

```
var modulo = require('./modulo');
modulo.foo = "newFoo";
console.log(modulo.foo);
console.log(modulo.myFunction.innerFunction());
```

**modulo.js**

```
var foo = "oldFoo";
var myFunction = (function(innerFoo) {
  return {
    innerFunction: function () {
      return "Returning innerFunction with " + innerFoo;
    }
  };
})(foo);

module.exports.foo = foo;
module.exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

Now when I execute `node index.js` the result is:

```
newFoo
Returning innerFunction with oldFoo
```

How can I pass the *newFoo* variable so *modulo.js* can use it internally?

(Actually, I want to pass a socket so my *module.js* can use it for communication with the server)

Thank you very much in advance!!

## EDIT: SOLUTION

**modulo.js**

```
module.exports.foo = "";
var myFunction = (function() {

  return {
    innerFunction: function () {
      var innerFoo = module.exports.foo;
      return "Returning innerFunction with " + innerFoo;
    }
  };
})();

module.exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your IIFE does *not* read from `module.foo`, which you are overwriting, but from the actual `foo` variable in `modulo.js`. Javascript is Pass-by-value with primitive values ;)

Comment: So there's no way of injecting that variable from "outside"? Like a Socket, a context (this) or anything else… (Thanks for being so quick!!)

Comment: You could just use `module.foo` instead of innerFoo inside your function. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @reg4in. I changed what I was passing to the function and, although I don't really understand the difference between module.exports.foo and exports, it seems to be fine for me right now. Could you take a look at the edited answer? Thanks!

Comment: Hm. Not to offend you, but this looks horribly wrong to me. You could just remove the first line and instead of `myModule.foo` write `module.exports.foo`.

Comment: BUT you'd have to write `module.exports.foo = <whatever>` before that.

Comment: Well, my idea for this was to avoid repeating `module.exports.foo` many times in the code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81511/discussion-between-miguel-and-reg4in).